# Flutter .exe Release not running on Windows

Tags: windows, flutter, exe, flutter-build, flutter-windows

When I build flutter for windows with `flutter build windows` it generates a .exe file with its .dll files etc. However, running that file (.exe) gives me a white screen and my app is not running normally.

Running `flutter run --release -d windows` however builds my app normally and I can use it.

What is wrong here that running the .exe file is not starting my app properly?

This is my release folder structure when running `flutter build windows`:

[image]

Running the .exe file:

[image]

Comment: can you try `flutter clean` and again rebuild the app

Comment: @YeasinSheikh still not working

Comment: Can you the same approach on different project

Comment: on a brand new flutter project, the .exe runs fine, but I have no idea what could cause this. Even when I remove all custom code from the build method in .main the issue still appears. I think maybe it's an issue with a third party library but I don't know how I could address this. @YeasinSheikh

Comment: could be, you can check the package if those are supported for windows. also if something went wrong with source, you create a copy of the project and run `flutter create .`.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh sqlite was causing the issue. I was initializing it in the main method. See the answered question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using `sqflite_common_ffi` on Windows and this was causing the issue. Initializing it was only valid for debug thus I had to add the [sqlite3.dll](https://www.dll-files.com/sqlite3.dll.html) to the release build folder. Then it worked fine like before when starting the .exe file.

Detailed description can be found here: https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/issues/574

Comment: you can download sqlite3.dll official file from here
 https://www.sqlite.org/download.html[link](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html)